# How to update the busyIndicator status in a viewmodel method?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a webservice call and I want to update The UI busyIndicator status when the webservice receives an error!
This is the code in the viewmodel webservice call completed method:

```
if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                    busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
                    return;
                }
```

I know how to update the UI object in another thread when it has multiple threads, but the viewmodel doesn't have a reference to the busyIndicator!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MVVM patter do something like this

XAML file

```
  <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator BusyContent="Fetching Data Please Wait.." IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" >
            <Grid >....</Grid>
        </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

VIew Model class

```
private bool isBusy = false; 

public bool IsBusy 

{ 

    get { return isBusy; } 

    internal set { isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy"); }
```

No you just need to set value for property that will do the work for you

Something like in view model

```
    IsBusy = true; //or false
```

---

have you tried something like this , i.e used Dispatcher to update UI

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
//busyIndicator.BusyContent = "Fetching Data...";

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
{
Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => busyIndicator.IsBusy = false);
});
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the updating is the problem, he just can't call busyIndicator, he doesn't have a reference in its viewmodel. ALso, as he is using viewmodels, I'm assuming this is MVVM and click events can't be handled in this way.

Comment: I thought about this way , just want to know how to update it without binding.

Comment: @mantov - in that case  you nee to pass busyindicator of xaml as parameter to methor ot in the viewmodel class than you can change value for that busy indicator

Comment: the second way is compile error! beacuse the viewmodel class do not have a  reference on the UI page 's busyIndicator!

Comment: @mantov - as i mention you need to pass your ui busyindicator to the viewmodel that is the only way i think for the thing you want..

Comment: i think it have two way let the viewmodel know the busyIndicator object.

Comment: @mantov - welcome dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 1):

Bind the Busy Indicator Content to a string.
And set the value to what you want to display.

```
if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
                busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
                IndicatorMessage = "There has been an error"
                return;
            }
```

And in your XAML you do the standard binding.